# Can a bot click a link that makes a modal window in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, analytics

I have a form that launches in a modal window (fancybox to be exact) that loads a page that triggers an event in Google Analytics. I'm trying to keep bots from clicking it.

Since the fancybox uses jQuery to load the html page, can a bot reach the page and trigger the event? I'm trying to determine if the events are real.

I'm getting a difference between unique events and total events and trying to explain why there would be a discrepancy. Is the only way to explain it as genuine people clicking or could it be bots?

Comment: It probably can, I am not sure at 100% but this might interess you :   http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157
I think it may be considered as Dynamically inserted content

Comment: Can't give you a definite answer, but I've never encountered a bot filling out a form on my websites that contained some JavaScript (to display the form, to send the form etc.). But theoretically - yes, it's possible.

Comment: It's not only possible, it's quite easy to do.  There's plenty of UIs that allow a user to "record" actions and "waitfor" responses / html changes - then play them back automatically, even applying load-tests where they do so 1000s of times/second.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, a bot can do that. There's many ways of creating bots, and different methods will make most bots undetectable unless you have some really complex checks in place. I believe reCaptcha has a tonne of checks for example, ranging from the movement of the mouse, the react time of the user, user agents and so on and so forth.

Bots can come in all shapes and forms, including some that might use [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) to imitate a user using an actual browser, or they could even be written in a lower level and move the mouse and cause key presses on a system level.

What it comes down to is how much energy/time you're willing to expend to make it harder for bots to do their thing. I doubt you'll ever get 100% accuracy on stopping bots.

But yes, a bot can trigger a button press event, or even press the button directly like a normal user would